# Using '|' from Bash's if construct prevents variable being set

Tags: bash, if-statement, pipe, pipeline

I've read that you can redirect I/O into and out of various constructs in Bash (such as "if" and "while").  When I was trying this out, I noticed that using a "|" at the end of an if construct prevented any variables that I overwrote inside the if construct from taking effect; but if I use ">" instead, then the variable modifications take effect.

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR_0='Unmodified'

if true
then
    VAR_0='Changed'
fi | cat

echo "VAR_0: $VAR_0"

###########

VAR_1='Unmodified'

if true
then
    VAR_1='Changed'
fi > tmpFile
rm tmpFile

echo "VAR_1: $VAR_1"
```

Running Bash version 4.3.11 on 64-bit Linux produces the following output:

```
VAR_0: Unmodified
VAR_1: Changed
```

Note the only difference is how I'm redirecting stdout from the if construct.  Why is the "|" preventing VAR_0 from being changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because pipelines use subshells; by piping to `cat`, you've made the first if-then block execute in a subshell. Hence, `VAR_0='Changed'` is changed, but only in the subshell.

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR_0='Unmodified'

if true
then
    VAR_0='Changed'
    echo "VAR_0: $VAR_0"
fi | cat

echo "VAR_0: $VAR_0"
```

Redirecting to a file ("`>`") does *not* create a subshell; thus that variable persists.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Check out [Bash FAQ 24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).
It answers your question along with provided examples!

---

You're creating a [SubShell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell) which in turn being discarded along with its variables copy of the parent shell.

Take the following common mistake as an example:

```
var=0
some-command | while read -r line; do
    printf 'var value inside subshell is: %s\n' "$((++var))"
done
printf 'But in the parent shell it stays: %s\n' "$var"
```

*Output:*

```
var value inside subshell is: 1
But in the parent shell it stays: 0
```

When this behvior is not desired, the solution is often to use [Process Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) to keep the varaibles updated. So, in our case ( or as can be seen generally in [Bash FAQ 24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) ) we do the following:

```
var=0
while read -r line; do
    printf 'var value inside subshell is: %s\n' "$((++var))"
done < <(some-command)
printf 'And it stays the same: %s\n' "$var"
```

*Output:*

```
var value inside subshell is: 1
And it stays the same: 1
```